# Get current path in Windows 8 WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf, directory, windows

I'm trying to bind images for my Windows 8 app but I currently am struggling with trying to know where the application diretory is.
I've read many threads about this but the Windows 8 namespaces do not contain the tools I've seen such as:

Directory.GetDirectory()

AppDomain

Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()

etc...

If anyone can tell me how to know where I should load my images from, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope here by Windows 8 app you mean Windows 8 (Silverlight) app.

Well by default it doesn't provide you access to current directory. The only thing you can do is to get access to temporary directory and use that storage:

```
StorageFolder temp = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder;
```

For further reference please consult to:
http://lunarfrog.com/blog/winrt-folders-access